# How can I run a python code on GPU in Colab

Tags: python, json, gpu, google-colaboratory

I have a small code with a large scale dataset(about 90,000 item in a json file).
I'm trying to select some of the data from that datadet and write in a new json file. Runnin that code takes a lot.
My first question is, if i run that code on GPU help to reduce running time?
And my second question is how can i make sure my python code is running on GPU?(i am using colab and i changed the runtime to GPU but it says you're not utilizing GPU).
This is my code:

```
Import json 
With open('file.json', 'r') as f:   
 Dict_1= json.load(f) 
Ls=[]

For i in Dict_1:  
 If i['answer']=='yes':   
  Ls.append(i)   
  With open('file2.json', 'w') as f2:    
   Json.dump(ls, f2)
```

Comment: why do you need gpu for processing part? You can use multiprocessing to reduce the time.

Comment: Could you please explain more or give me a link?

Comment: This will give you basic idea: https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929477/how-to-read-file-using-multiprocessing-pooling

Comment: GPU runs only code specially created for GPU and only specialized modules use GPU - i.e. `Tensorflow` - and loading JSON doesn't need GPU and Python doesn't have code which could use GPU for this. You need modules which could split data and run code on many threads or processes or many computers -  `threading`, `multiprocessing`, `joblib`, `ray`, `PySpark`,